# Get id value from list jsp

Tags: java, jsp, httprequest

I have view on my jsp like this:

```xml
<form:form name = "command" 
         method = "post" 
         action = "withdrawRequest" 
          class = "form-horizontal group-border-dashed" 
          style = "border-radius: 0px;">
<table class = "table table-bordered" 
          id = "datatable-icons" > <!-- start table table-bordered -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NO</th>
            <th>AMOUNT (RP)</th>
            <th>DOCTOR BALANCE (RP)</th>
            <th>DOCTOR ID</th>
            <th>DOCTOR NAME</th>
            <th>TRANSFER ADMIN NAME</th>
            <th>TRANSFER DATE</th>
            <th>TRANSFER REFERENCE</th>
            <th>TRANSFERRED</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var = "withdrawal" 
                 items = "${listWithdrawals}" 
             varStatus = "loopStatus">
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td>${withdrawal.id}</td>
            <td>${loopStatus.index + 1}</td>
            <td class="text-right"><fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${withdrawal.amount}" /></td>
            <td class="text-right"><fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${withdrawal.doctor_balance}" /></td>
            <td>${withdrawal.doctor_id}</td>
            <td>${withdrawal.doctor_name}</td>
            <td>${withdrawal.transfer_admin_name}</td>
            <td><%-- <fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${withdrawal.transfer_date}" /> --%>${withdrawal.transfer_date}</td>
            <td>${withdrawal.transfer_reference}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <c:if test="${withdrawal.transferred == true}">
                    <span class="label label-success">Transferred</span>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${withdrawal.transferred == false}">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm md-trigger" data-modal="form-primary" type="button">Pending</button>
                </c:if>
                <div class="md-modal colored-header danger custom-width md-effect-9" id="form-primary">
                    <div class="md-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3>Confirm Withdrawal Request</h3>
                            <button type="button" class="close md-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Admin Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adminName" value="${adminName}">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="${withdrawal.id}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Transfer Reference</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="transferReference" value="${transferReference}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat md-close" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat md-close" name="submitRequest">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form:form>
```

I cannot get the ID of which button I selected from view,

```xml
<input type = "text" 
      class = "form-control" 
       name = "id" 
      value = "${withdrawal.id}" />
```

If I use this code

```xml
String withdrawalId = request.getParameter("id");
```

The value is always 120.
For example:

[image]

How do I get the correct ID when I click the modal window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in **Nifty Modal Window Effects** you are using for popup. It opens modal window for the last row.

It can be fixed with following jsp modifications.

1. Move modal window declaration out of table. Make it single for page. And rename id field to make it unique, e.g. `transferredId`
2. Add `onclick` to buttons opening modal window in order to init it (set transferredId and others) with necessary values

So your form would be (just ending to save space)

```
                ....
                <td class="text-center">
                ....
                <c:if test="${withdrawal.transferred == false}">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm md-trigger" data-modal="form-primary" type="button"
                    onclick="document.getElementById('transferredId').value=${withdrawal.id}">
                    Pending
                    </button>
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="md-modal colored-header danger custom-width md-effect-9" id="form-primary">
    <div class="md-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Confirm Withdrawal Request</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close md-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Admin Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adminName" value="${adminName}">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="transferredId" id="transferredId" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Transfer Reference</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="transferReference">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat md-close" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat md-close" name="submitRequest">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After that `String withdrawalId = request.getParameter("transferredId");` will return correct id.

Comment: aaaaaak you are the best broo, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated HTML. Looks to me that it contains `listWithdrawals.length` instances of that `<input` and all of them have the same name.

`request.getParameter("id")` is going to return a single value, not a list of all the values. What you need is `request.getParamaterValues("id")` that is going to return all of them.

This is because when the form is submitted *all* those input values are going to be sent.

So the simple solution (with no JavaScript magic) is to get all the lists of values with `request.getParamaterValues` and deal with everything that changed. `ids[0]` and `transferReferences[0]` would be the needed values for the first item in `listWithdrawals`:

```
String[] ids = request.getParamaterValues("id");
String[] transferReferences = request.getParamaterValues("transferReference");

for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ids[i]);
    System.out.println(transferReferences[i]);
}
```

**Another solution** would be to generate unique names for each input/item in `listWithdrawals`:

```
<c:forEach var="withdrawal" items="${listWithdrawals}" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="${'transferReference_'.concat(withdrawal.id)}" value="${withdrawal.id}" />
</c:forEach>
```

And then you'd be able to access the `transferReference` value of a `withdrawal` with ID 119 like this:

```
request.getParameter("transferReference_119")
```

Comment: if iam using that, i wll get all of them id, how to spesific them?

Comment: See my updated answer. There's no way you can get JUST the one you opened the modal for. It's a normal HTML form you submit, it's normal that you'll get all the values. Your problem and my solutions are dealing with this, discerning between all the returned items.

Comment: if my trigger using button from modal window, how to implement it?

Comment: You are using a `<button type="submit"`, of course it is submitting your whole form. You can know which one of the submit buttons was pressed by giving it a unique value. Only the one pressed will be sent. So `<input type="submit" name="submitRequest" value="${withdrawal.id}"...` and then `request.getParameter("submitRequest")` and you'll get the value of the button you pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for not add this as a comment, as i can't because i still not have 50 reputation (still 16), i just want you to test something, try to refresh the page, and open row with ID 119 for example first time, i mean any Id rather than 120, and see what happen, if the value that you opened first time is always still exist, so the problem is not in id 120 and the problem is that u may use if not null to set the value some where, so first time it will be null and the value added to it, but next times it will have a value already so u can't change it, and if u can't solve the problem after doing that, please upload your controller so we can detect the problem